# Отладка библиотеки в MonoDevelop

Tags: отладка, mono, monodevelop, embedded

В общем, есть приложение со встроенным рантаймом моно.
И нужно иметь возможность отлаживать сборки, которые загружаются в рантайм.

Вот так выглядит метод инициализации моно в приложении:

```
const char* options[] = { "--debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:10000" };
mono_jit_parse_options(sizeof(options)/sizeof(char*), (char**)options);
mono_debug_init(MONO_DEBUG_FORMAT_MONO);

mono_set_dirs(mono_lib, mono_etc);
mDomain = mono_jit_init_version("AppDomain", "v4.0");

mono_debug_domain_create(mDomain);
```

При отладке в MonoDevelop через soft debugger брейкпоинт срабатывает, только если вызывать `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()`. Причем отображается только дизассемблированый код моей библиотеки, так же если щелкать step info и дело доходит до вызовов в системных библиотеках, то уже отображаются исходники этих системных библиотек.

В настройках проекта везде выставлены галки для дебага.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде решил путем копирования mdb, после сборки, в рабочую папку с dll